# What is the main purpose for confirmation of commitment?

Tags: support, area-51

In area51 when you commit to any proposal, It won't be appear to others until you confirm the commitment from mail. Is this really necessary or what is the purpose of doing this??
I am asking this question because, I don't have mail access in my company so my commitments are pending yet just because mail commitment.

Answer (score 2):

It should suffice to confirm your email address once, then commitment won't require another mail. (At least that's what I extrapolate from my experience, I had my mail confirmed after registering and when I commit the is no confirmation required)